# Deserialize Json with invalid markup

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm currently trying to tackle a situation where we have invalid Json that we are trying to deserialize. The clinch point is we're supplied Json where property assignment is declared with an `=` instead of a `:` character.

Example Json:

```
{
    "Field1" = "Hello",
    "Field2" = "Stuff",
    "Field3" = "I am non-Json Json, fear me",
    "Field4" = 8
}
```

Has anyone had any luck using Json.Net to deserialize this into an object of relating structure into C# where `=` is in use instead of `:`

I've been trying to write a `JsonConverter` to read past the `=` but it always complains it's got an `=` instead of a `:` and throws an exception with the message "Expected ':' but got: =. Path ''".

I don't see any way past this except for writing my own deserialization process and not using the Json.Net library. which sucks for something so close to being valid Json (But I suppose is fair enough as it is invalid)

When `reader.ReadAsString();` is hit it should read `Field1` out but obviously it hasn't met its friend the `:` yet and so proceeds to fall over saying "what the hell is this doing here?!". I've not got any `JsonConverter` implementation examples because there's really not much to show. just me attempting to use any of the "Read..." methods and failing to do so.

Comment: If  property assignment is declared with an = instead of a : character then it is not JSON. period. If you don't expect any `=` in the values of the object then you can do a `String.Replace("=", ":")` and then try to parse it

Comment: Give the supplier of this file a stern talking to about standards and if they plan to use json, that they should implement it correctly? Why would you need to do the effort, when clearly the supplier is sending out an incorrect format (though I think @Nkosi answer might be the easier one, it could give also some "unexpected" results in case you actually get passed a = in the string content (and replacing the string value itself might be also anoying, nl, what do you do with the intentional : signs))

Comment: If you wanted a slightly safer option than a `String.Replace` you could probably concoct a regular expression that would ensure any "=" inside of the data wasn't converted. However, I agree with @Icepickle, talk to the provider and tell them to fix their crap.

Comment: These are all very good points. The supplier of this "Json" is insisting we must accept their data as is and I think we're too far down the line to start telling them their format is incorrect (Even though it is, yay for customers!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If property assignment is declared with an `=` instead of a `:` character then it is not JSON.

If you don't expect any = in the values of the object then you can do a

```
string json = invalidData.Replace("=", ":");
```

and then try to parse it.

As mentioned by @Icepickle, there are risks involved in doing this.

My answer works as a quick fix/workaround, but you will eventually need to make sure that the data you are receiving is valid JSON.

There is no point in trying to deserialize invalid JSON.

Comment: I think this is the best we're going to get given the situation. We can guarantee (at least they say they never will) there will never be an = or a : in the field name of their data so this is what we're going to roll with. I think we can all agree it's not nice or "good form" but that's life.

Comment: @Skintkingle not only the field name, but also the value of the field should never have this, and I don't think they can guarantee this (at least not if they are free to fill in text strings)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by others, the easiest way to get around this issue is to use a simple string replace to change `=` characters to `:` within the JSON string prior to parsing it.  Of course, if you have any data values that have `=` characters in them, they will be mangled by the replacement as well.

If you are worried that the data will have `=` characters in it, you could take this a step further and use Regex to do the replacement.  For example, the following Regex will only replace `=` characters that immediately follow a quoted property name:

```
string validJson = Regex.Replace(invalidJson, @"(""[^""]+"")\s?=\s?", "$1 : ");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yvydi2

---

Another possible solution is to alter the Json.Net source code to allow an `=` where a `:` normally appears in valid JSON.  This is probably the safest option in terms of parsing, but requires a little more effort.  If you want to go this route, download the latest [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) from GitHub, and open the solution in Visual Studio 2015.   Locate the [JsonTextReader](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) class in the root of the project.  Inside this class is a private method called `ParseProperty`.  Near the end of the method is some code which looks like this:

```
if (_chars[_charPos] != ':')
{
    throw JsonReaderException.Create(this, "Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: {0}.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _chars[_charPos]));
}
```

If you change the above `if` statement to this:

```
if (_chars[_charPos] != ':' && _chars[_charPos] != '=')
```

then the reader will allow both `:` and `=` characters as separators between property names and values.  Save the change, rebuild the library, and you should be able to use it on your "special" JSON.

Comment: This is a beautiful Idea. I actually really like the idea of modifying the Json.Net code in this way and maintaining it locally. I would be sad that I cant keep it up to date via NuGet though. There's always downsides to these things I guess. This is something we are going to plan into to make this solution better in the future. Thanks for the idea it really is a great one.

Comment: Indeed, the problem with modifying the source code locally is that you have to keep reapplying the change any time you want to update it to the latest version from the master repo.  Normally the solution to that is to contribute the fix back to the master project, but in this case the change is so specialized I doubt it would be accepted.